# Как закрепить flex элемент справа сверху?

Tags: css

В флекс каталоге есть меню и товары, как закрепить меню в правом верхнем углу так, чтобы товары обтекали его слева и снизу?
https://jsfiddle.net/4roj2ced/

```css
.catalog{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.menu{
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 230px;
  
}

.product{
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="catalog">
  <div class="menu"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Развернуть направление?

Comment: flex-direction: row-reverse

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex тогда и товары направление поменяют, чего быть не должно

Comment: По-моему это тот редкий случай, когда нужны флоаты

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jawrz6Ly/

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex флоаты, вроде бы, не работают во флекс. А нужен именно флекс, тк товары не фиксированной высоты и ширины, они расширяются в зависимости от того, что внутри них и делят пространство снаружи

Comment: Ты не сделаешь это на флексах. Что тут не так? https://jsfiddle.net/Lx05aqc2/

Comment: Высота должна быть у всех одинаковая, по самому высокому.
А ширина свойством flex-grow: 1 задается

Comment: Не знаю...может кто-нибудь другой подскажет, потому что я не вижу никаких других решений ни на флексах ни на гридах. Могу попробовать на js что-нибудь сделать, но это уже завтра.

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex Спасибо, js не нужно) Отделю это все и обойдусь без обтекания меню снизу.

Comment: так а что именно не так в предложенном фидле? чет ничего не понятно